# C/C++ language - POINTERS and ARITHMETIC... Exception Code: c0000005

Tags: c++, c, pointers

The code below is compiled correctly, however when it is executed,
the console displays the following error... Exception Code: c0000005.
The error occurs in the following line:

```
*cptr++ = hextbl[((tval >> 4) & 0x0F)];
```

This error is about improper access to memory.
This way, I believe that the error may be something that I still do
not understand right about pointers and arithmetic...

```
#include <stdio.h>

// function prototypes
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]);
char *put_hexbyte(char *cptr, char tval);

// main routine
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) // variables to get arguments
{
    char val = 65;     // 0x41 >>> I need 2 bytes 0x34 and 0x31,
                       // they are ASCII from 0x41 (0x34 = "4" and 0x31 = "1")
    char *bufASCII;    // pointer to store these ASCII

    bufASCII = put_hexbyte(bufASCII, val);

    return 0;
}


// Put a byte as hex ASCII, return pointer to next location.
char *put_hexbyte(char *cptr, char tval) 
{
    static char hextbl[16] =
    {
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
    };

    printf("at this point, all is OK!!!\n"); // <<< OK!
    *cptr++ = hextbl[((tval >> 4) & 0x0F)];  // <<< memory violation error! (Exception Code: c0000005)
    *cptr++ = hextbl[tval & 0x0F];

    return(cptr);
}
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: `*cptr++ = hextbl[((tval >> 4) & 0x0F)];` is one of the most convoluted and obfuscated ways to index an array that I've ever seen.

Comment: What *valid* memory does `cptr` point to when you enter the function and start dereferencing it? This is more basic than pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @molbdnilo Your comment actually answers the question. But only if one is willing to see through its inflammatory style, and only for people who already understand how pointers work in C.

Comment: @anatolyg: I don't see molbdnilo's comment as inflammatory.  It is a valid, non-incendiary question used as a technique to point out that there is a problem in the code, a technique that is thousands of years old (Socrates used questions like this to point out flaws in arguments in ancient Greece, for example).

Comment: thank you @anatolyg by his way of seeing the things... and sorry about my poor English (and poor C, eheheheheheheeee ), thank you!

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, there are ways to talk to people, especially for a beginner that is requesting help... If I understood right on pointers, I would not here asking this basic question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pointer:

```
char *bufASCII;
```

Is uninitialised. And then you write to it:

```
*cptr++ = x;
```

You need to initialise it first, otherwise using it is undefined behavior. For instance:

```
char *bufASCII = new char[2];
```

Although even then, this:

```
bufASCII = put_hexbyte(bufASCII, val);
```

would lose track of your original pointer. If you want the return value for the end of buffer, you should store that separateyl:

```
char* eob = put_hexbyte(bufASCII, val);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that a pointer to the end of the buffer is next to useless - the buffer is too short to append anything to it (e.g. `'\0'`). Maybe you should allocate some more (no way to know how much), or just use `std::string` (the question is tagged c++ but the tag seems irrelevant).

Comment: @anatolyg, thanks... the Barry's tip, worked very well! And now that I understand how to prepare a pointer, I can do other things that I need, with a larger size. :)

Comment: @Barry, double thanks for you!!! One to solve my question and another by the start (original) point tip!  His response was: short (the right size), polite and effective. :)

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
char *bufASCII;    // pointer to store these ASCII
```

Is a pointer to character, but it actually doesn't point to anything yet, hence you can't write to that pointer.